# Index of circle containing fixed point

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

Given

$\dot x = x^2-y^4 $ and $ \dot y = y^2 -x^4 $

Find the index of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ with $a < 1$

Attempt:

I employed linear analysis by finding all the fixed points.  There are five total but the one at interest is the origin (0,0).  Finding the trace and determinant of the Jacobian for this system classifies this fixed point as a non-isolated stable node which has an index of +1.  Since a circle of a < 1 only contains this fixed point,  the index of the circle is equal to +1.

What is another way of reaching the same conclusion?  I was thinking to evaluate the index by evaluating the integral over the circle but it looked messy.  Any thoughts?

Comment: "Finding the trace and determinant of the Jacobian for this system classifies this fixed point as a non-isolated stable node which has an index of +1" This is in need of some serious explanations: first, the trace and determinant of the Jacobian matrix at (0,0) are both zero hence they do not allow to determine the type of the fixed point; second, (0,0) is very much an *isolated* fixed point; third, considering circles centered at (0,0) with vanishing radiuses, the index seems to be 0.

Comment: How could this be if the isolated fixed point is enclosed by the area of the contour where the contour is the circle centered at origin with radius a <1.  The index would be zero if there are no fixed points enclosed, correct?

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~jlirion/course_notes/MAT_119A_Final_Notes.pdf

Take a look at the section "Properties of the Index"

Comment: Yes, and no part of the section applies, do they? The text states the (true) result that, if there is no fixed point enclosed, then the index is zero, not the other implication.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that the only way to get an index of zero for a contour is to have no fixed points enclosed.  This is the first time I have come across a case where  fixed point is enclosed and the index is zero.

Comment: Did you try "to evaluate the index by evaluating the integral over the circle", simply to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the index remains unchanged under homotopies of the closed path that avoid the fixed points. In this case, we have
$$
(x',y')=(x^2,y^2)-(y^4,x^4),
$$
and so on the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ with $|a|$ very small the term $(x^2,y^2)$ determines the index, since
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\|(y^4,x^4)\|}{\|(x^2,y^2)\|}=0.
$$
In other words, for $|a|$ very small, the index is the same as that of $(x',y')=(x^2,y^2)$, namely $0$.

Comment: Right, namely $0$.